# Web Scraping Co-Sponsors on NYS Bills using Google Sheets using IMPORTXML

Tags: arrays, web-scraping, google-sheets, filter, import

I am currently trying to write a formula in Google Sheets so that it will take the co-sponsors for a NYS and put them into my google sheet. The formula that I wrote is:

*=IMPORTXML(https://nyassembly.gov/leg/?term=2021&bn=S01184, "//*[@id='legcontent']/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]").

//*[@id='legcontent']/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2] is the xPath for the data that I am trying to extract which I copied from the HTML on the website.

I am getting the error "Formula Parsing Error", however, I do not see where the error is. It would be much appreciated if anyone could help out!

Answer (score 3):

use:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://nyassembly.gov/leg/?term=2021&bn=S01184", 
 "table", 1), 7, 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Another way of getting the same would be `=IMPORTXML("https://nyassembly.gov/leg/?term=2021&bn=S01184","//td[.='COSPNSR']/../td[2]/text()")`. Your answer always provides something new for me to learn.